# Git merging 2 repos not syncing file deletions

Tags: git, github, merge

I have two repos, A and B, where A is the "leader" and B is the "follower" that syncs to get all of A's changes. B can also make its own changes (e.g. add other files that don't exist in A) but it needs to stay in sync with A by running a script that merges all the changes from A into B.

The merging is working when I make updates to files in A and then B gets those updates.

The problem is when I make file deletions in A. B doesn't pick them up but just ignores those changes and keeps those files in B, without deleting them. The deleted files are committed and pushed in A so I expected them to also get deleted in B when the sync script is run.

I have tried the following [git merge strategies](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies) but they all result in the same problem, where a deleted file in repo A doesn't get deleted in repo B:

- ort theirs
- ours
- default
- recursive subtree (this syncs the deleted file from A to B but it deletes B's files that don't exist in A, which is not the desired behavior)
- recursive patience
- recursive ours
- recursive theirs

I'm running this script (`github-sync.sh`) in GitHub Actions in repo B to sync the 2 repos. Repo A is public and repo B is private. The private repo needs to stay in sync with the public repo but is free to make its own changes.

In the script, `upstream` is referring to repo A (`https://github.com/gomisha/repo-sync-test-public`). I'm running this script as a GitHub Action in repo B (a private GitHub repo).

```
#!/bin/sh
set -ex

# need to set GitHub Actions bot user name and email to avoid "Committer identity unknown" error
# https://github.com/actions/checkout/discussions/479

git config --global user.email "github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
git config --global user.name "github-actions"
git remote add upstream  https://github.com/gomisha/repo-sync-test-public
git remote -v
git fetch upstream --quiet

# need to use "--no-edit" for merging to bypasses manual step of editing merge commit message file
# need to use "recursive theirs" strategy for merging - otherwise get merge conflicts
# need to use "--allow-unrelated-histories" for merging - otherwise get errors about divergent branches:
# fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.

# tried the following merge strategies with no success of merging a deleted from from upstream repo
# git merge --no-edit -s subtree --allow-unrelated-histories upstream/main
# git merge --no-edit -s recursive -X theirs --allow-unrelated-histories upstream/main
# git merge --no-edit -s recursive -X patience --allow-unrelated-histories upstream/main
# git merge --no-edit --allow-unrelated-histories upstream/main
# git merge --no-edit -s ours --allow-unrelated-histories upstream/main

git merge --no-edit -s ort -Xtheirs --allow-unrelated-histories upstream/main
git push
```

If I make a new file in A (e.g. `hello1.go`), B will pick it up. If I make updates to that file in A, B will again pick that up. The problem is when I delete that file in A, B will just ignore that deletion and leave that file in B.

Comment: That doesn't sound quite right. Can you create a sequence of commands starting with `git init` that replicates the problem? I think you won't be able to _and_ because of trying to replicate it, you will be able to figure out what you are doing wrong or how your assumptions about either git or your workflow are wrong.

Comment: This is done in GitHub on existing repos so there's no need for `git init`. It's a workflow for syncing 2 existing repos.